# How to hide / show a GIF image in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

In using Python's Tkinter application, I have come across a little problem. How do I hide and show GIF images that I have put into the window using PhotoImage?

I can make the images appear in the first place, but am unable to do anything with them. I have tried using canvas.itemconfig and canvas.update, but to no avail. Is anyone able to solve this problem?

```
picture = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\ZecFamily5\\Downloads\\Island.gif')
c.create_image(250, 250, image=picture)
```

The above code cannot be hidden or shown using c.itemconfig(image, state=HIDDEN).

Comment: Please insert some minimal code that will create a window and display a gif image using the same calls you are doing there. It will make a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Hiding it depends on how you make it visible in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `.itemconfig(Your Item Name, state=HIDDEN)` and to show, change HIDDEN to NORMAL to show.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the [ImageTK](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm) module:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
```

As it should allow you to make a TKinter compatible photo image.
For this to work though, do keep in mind that this will need to be at the beginning of your file:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Here is an example piece of code to show you what I mean:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

path = 'C:/xxxx/xxxx.jpg'

root = tk.Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to hide an image. The OP already says they know how to make the image appear.